# Segmentation Fault when using command-line arguments

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, random-seed

I'm new to programming. Following is a program I wrote to calculate the probability distribution of random 6-sided dice throws. It works perfectly, however if I use command-line argument for number of throws, it starts throwing up segmentation fault error. Can somebody help me understand what I am doing wrong ?

```
// distribution of rand numbers

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

const unsigned short NUM_FACES = 6;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2 || isdigit(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Invalid arguments!!\n");
        printf("Usage: %s numThrows\n", argv[0]);                      //correct usage of arguments
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    system("clear");

    srand(time(0));                                                    //updating seed
    long upperLim = atol(argv[1]);
    long dist[7] = {0};
    double probab = 0.0;
    unsigned int i;
    for(i = 0; i < upperLim; i++)
        ++dist[rand()%6 + 1];                                         //generating random numbers (1-6)

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_FACES; i++)
    {
        probab = 100.0*dist[i]/upperLim;                              //calculating probability of each throws
        printf("DICE THROW %d ->     Number of throws: %ld     Distribution: %.2lf%c\n", i+1, dist[i], probab, '%');
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
isdigit(argv[1])
```

`isdigit` wants an `int`, not a `char *`

If you want to ckeck if all characters are digits you can use something like:

```
bool strIsDigit(const char *str)
{
    while (*str)
    {
        if (!isdigit((unsigned char)*str++))
        {
             return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome ;), you should always compile with warnings on